# Javascript - onsubmit activating on pageload

Tags: javascript, onsubmit

I have the following javascript code.

```
window.onload = function init() {


var appForm = document.getElementById("application");
appForm.onsubmit = validate();
```

}

I want the validate function to only occur once someone has clicked the 'submit' button on the page, but the form is validating as soon as the page loads. What do I need to change to fix this?
Thanks!

edit: Thanks bozdoz, that worked perfectly.

Comment: Remove the brackets after `validate`.  It is executing the function immediately, instead of setting `onsubmit` to the function.

Comment: You are associating the function on "window.onload". It would run whenever the window completes loading. You need to change that to submit button with some id and "onclick" action.

Comment: I'm not seeing a need have your `window.onload = function init(){}`. Could just be `onload = function(){}`.

Answer (score 1):

You are executing the function which probably doesn't return another unexecuted function. `onsubmit` must be assigned a function name, which is basically a variable, or an Anonymous function. Change

```
appForm.onsubmit = validate();
```

to

```
appForm.onsubmit = validate;
```

or

```
appForm.onsubmit = function(){
  validate(arg0, arg1, arg2); // preferred way if your function takes arguments
}
```

Note that when any JavaScript Event occurs the only thing that is passed to the Anonymous function or a function like `validate` is just the Event Object, so you must pass arguments of your own using the bottom example.